# Data driven view of associations vs. Behavior driven view of associations

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram

From `UML user guide`,chapter 5, I've found the following:

---

To model structural relationships,

- For each pair of classes, if you need to navigate from objects of one to objects of another, specify an association between the two. This is a `data-driven view of associations`.
- For each pair of classes, if objects of one class need to interact with objects of the other class other than as parameters to an operation, specify an association between the two. This is more of a `behavior-driven view of associations`

---

And this is my understanding about the first type of association,`data-driven view of associations` through the following example: a class, User, with three attributes, one of which is another class, Address.

```
class User {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   Address address;
}

class Address {
      String streetName;
      int    streetNumber;
      String postalCode;

}
```

and the UML diagram of the above situation is:

[image]

Note that the third attribute of `User` converted to association end(as far as I know because it is of Address class type)

My questions:

1- Is this the correct interpretation of `data-driven view of associations`?

2- What about `behavior-driven view of associations`? is there an example explains it?

Answer (score 0):

Data - driven associations are normal associations with aggregation, multiplicity, navigability and all these things. They are well defined.

Behavior-driven associations you use when showing functions that belong to one class and use other class instance as a parameter or the result. Also here belongs any complex connection, such as "listens", "registers" and so on. They are shown as dependencies, maybe with some additional letter, such as <<u>> (usage). They are not strictly defined and can't be used for code generation.

Don't believe much to the words "UML user guide" - all of them are simply books and are not the part of UML standard. They are not saint and are full of personal views (and alas, fallacies) of authors. Nowhere in UML standard is forbidden to use Dependencies for showing the use of other class in some parameter list.